# Upgrade ansible to use python3 on controller

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, ansible

I want to change ansible to use python3.5 on the controller. I already have ansible and python3.5 installed, is there a way to just change it to use python3?

The ansible doc have suggested testing python3 with ansible with `python3 /usr/bin/ansible localhost -m ping`. But don't give any more detail if this doesn't work.

My result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 32, in <module>
        from ansible import context
ImportError: No module named 'ansible'
```

I have also tried to pip3 install ansible without luck:

```
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-eadti4n6/ansible/setup.py", line 12
        print "Ansible now needs setuptools in order to build. " \
                                                               ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Comment: You would need to uninstall Ansible for python2 and then install it for python3 via a `pip` associated with python3.

Answer (score 5):

Following the directions on the Ansible [Python 3 Support](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html) page, I installed Ansible using `pip3` after removing the previous (2.7) version:

```
$ sudo -H pip uninstall ansible
$ sudo -H pip3 install ansible
```

When I got the `ImportError: No module named 'ansible'` error, I verified Ansible was accessible, and discovered `ansible-playbook` is simply a Python script:

```
$ which ansible
$ less /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
```

I thought perhaps something had gone wrong with the installation, so I redid it:

```
$ sudo -H pip uninstall ansible
$ sudo -H pip3 install ansible
```

The original uninstall had only asked about removing two things, this time a laundry list was presented.  The reinstall didn't download anything, apparently collecting everything from its cache.

I tried re-running my playbook and again got the `ImportError: No module named 'ansible'` error.  This led to an interesting discovery:

```
$ ansible --version
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 34, in <module>
        from ansible import context
    ImportError: No module named ansible
```

I then ran `less /usr/bin/ansible` and discovered the shebang in the script called for `#!/usr/bin/python` which I suspected was an error.  I edited the file, and changed the shebang to call for the python3 interpreter.  The result was very telling:

```
ansible --version
    ansible 2.9.2
      config file = /home/MAGICLEAP/fkoschara/.ansible.cfg
      configured module search path = ['/home/MAGICLEAP/fkoschara/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
      ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ansible
      executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
      python version = 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Apparently the `pip3` install failed to set the correct shebang for the `ansible` executable.  Searching all of `/usr/bin/ansible*` I discovered `ansible-connection` also had a `python` shebang, rather than a `python3` one, but all of the other files were correct.

After fixing the incorrect shebangs, my playbook ran correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: *I want to change ansible to use python3.5 on the controller (Ubuntu).*

A: Latest ansible 2.8 package in Ubuntu 18.04 uses Python2

```
> cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_launchpad_net_ansible_ansible_2_8_ubuntu.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible-2.8/ubuntu bionic main

> ansible --version
ansible 2.8.4
[...]
python version = 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

But it is possible to use Python3 at remote hosts if available. For example

```
> grep test_01 hosts
test_01 ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.6

> ansible test_01 -m ping -vvv
ansible 2.8.4
[...]
python version = 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) [GCC 7.3.0]
[...]
```

> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="admin"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 
>   [...]
>   BECOME-SUCCESS-lwccvmomxxdjjpbipvzertvrtfluaqbt ; **/usr/local/bin/python3.6**'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
>   Escalation succeeded
>    (0, '\n{"ping": "pong", "invocation": {"module_args": {"data": "pong"}}}\n', '')

If you really need "Ansible Python3 at master" you might want to try pip. See [pip install ansible](https://pypi.org/project/ansible/). It's available for both Python2 and Python3. Be careful to set the paths properly. To be sure what are you running deinstall Ubuntu ansible packages.

Comment: Ansible will use Python 3 if it's available and `pip3` is used to install Ansible - but the installation may need to be fixed, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps a rather quick setup, could be achieved using virtual environments:

1. Create a virtual environment e.g. ANSIBLEENV with the desired python version e.g. python3:

`python3 -m venv ANSIBLEENV`

2. Activate the virtual environment:

`source ANSIBLENV/bin/activate`

3. Setup a `requirements.txt` with the desired ansible version e.g ansible 2.9.10 (and other modules maybe):

`ansible == 2.9.10`

Now you're gonna have a sandbox with the desired python and ansible version, which is very useful when you have multiple python version on your system.

Also when you're installing packages via `pip` in your virtual environment you could do a `pip freeze >> requirements.txt` to have an updated requirements that can be used later on.